# How To Joining 2 Table Not Well-Formatted With Complex Condition and WildCard

Tags: mysql, sql, complexity-theory

Recently I am using MySQL as database for small tasking to joining 2 table like below:-

[image]

But I have problem regarding complexity query and some of data are not well-formatted like table A.Bill_No (01X) ---> B.No (1X) where "0"1X are not appear as value on column table B.No

I also need to choose on B.From = '*'ext'*' only as condition WITH longest Duration as you can see desired output like below:-

[image]

I don't have idea how to create query statement like that output but I am hoping anybody on this forum please help me if you facing a same problem like I am now.

Anyway thanks very much on advance for read and replying this question.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Show us your current query attempt, and tell us what's wrong with it.

Comment: `A` is not in a relational table format.

Comment: thank you #strawberry pink, #jarlh and #Gordon Linoff to reply and give some comment. #jarlh what I believe my difficulty how I can filter the longest duration each ID.

Answer (score 0):

I have a small progress to archive my output where I use SUBSTRING to equalize some value are not well-formatted as #Gordon Linoff mention earlier. To archive that I use the sql statement like below:-

```
Select
  a.id,
  b.no
From
  a Inner Join
  b On SubString(a.bill_no From 2 For 8 ) = b.no
```

Now, I need to filter the longest one duration for each ID if have more than one record on Table B to completed my query.

Please forums give me some advice to archive that, your kindness and helping I am are really appreciated.